# Completed event not working on sounds played through audiosprite in IE

Tags: html5-audio, createjs, soundjs

I am using :

```
                    createjs.Sound.play("Demo_Sound").on("complete", function () {
                       alert('fin.');
                    }, this);
```

When *Demo_Sound* is not in audioSprite but it is a normal sound then it calls the "complete" event in IE too.

This is not working. Any leads will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The audiosprites were very small in length (2,3 seconds). And the gap between audios was only 200ms. I increased this gap and combined more sounds in one sprite and it is working fine now.